# Can a OVERLAPPED read on a file handle complete synchronously?

Tags: winapi

When I'm doing a OVERLAPPED read on a file handle I usually handle both cases of completeion: ReadFile immediately returns TRUE or it returns FALSE and GetLastError() returns ERROR_IO_PENDING. But is this really necessary ? Will a OVERLAPPED read never complete synchonously ? Maybe the data is already in the cache and can rapidly provided to the ReadFile call synchronously.

Comment: [ReadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile): *"If a file or device is opened for asynchronous I/O, subsequent calls to functions such as `ReadFile` using that handle generally return immediately, but **can also behave synchronously** with respect to blocked execution. For more information see [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156932](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/156932)."*

Comment: Thanks a lot, IInspectable. Unfortunately that information can't be found in the documentation for ReadFile / WriteFile.

Comment: It is under [Synchronization and File Position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile#synchronization-and-file-position). If it doesn't show for you make sure to switch the documentation language to "en-us".

Comment: And is *lpNumberOfBytesRead valid if ReadFile completes synchronously, or do I have do GetOverlappedResult in both cases ?

Comment: Again, from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile): *"If* hFile *was opened with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` [...] the* lpNumberOfBytesRead *parameter should be set to `NULL`."*

Comment: The ReadFile documentation says: This parameter __can__ be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL.

Comment: No, the documentation states *both*. The `lpNumberOfBytesRead` argument is strictly a convenience for synchronous operations. It allows clients to pass the address of a local variable, full well knowing that once the synchronous call retires, no one is going to dereference that pointer at some future time. If you launch an asynchronous request that returns `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, there is no going back in time. You are now responsible for keeping the variable whose address you handed out alive. So now instead of having to manage the lifetime of only the `OVERLAPPED` structure, you will also...

Comment: have to manage the lifetime of that other bit of data. That makes the API even harder to use. So if you intend to launch a request that potentially retires asynchronously, using the convenience parameter that's intended for synchronous operations only becomes inconvenient.

Comment: if `ReadFile` completed synchronously with success ( return *true* ) the and you pass not 0 `lpNumberOfBytesRead` - data under this pointer will be valid

Comment: @IInspectable - *You are now responsible for keeping the variable whose address you handed out alive.* - no, this is false. pointer *lpNumberOfBytesRead* (if not 0) must be valid only until `ReadFile` return, because this pointer used only inside `ReadFile` api. so possible use local variable for this and exit from function, even if I/O not completed. and this will be ok. always ok pass not 0 `lpNumberOfBytesRead` for `ReadFile`. but valid data here will be only in case `ReadFile` return *true*

Comment: *have to manage the lifetime of that other bit of data.* - you confuse *lpNumberOfBytesRead* with pointer to *OVERLAPPED* - the *lpOverlapped* must be valid until *I/O* not completed. the *lpNumberOfBytesRead* must be valid, how i say, only until `ReadFile` return

Comment: @rbm *"pointer* lpNumberOfBytesRead *(if not 0) must be valid only until `ReadFile` return"* - I wasn't able to determine this from the documentation. Where is this post condition spelled out?

Comment: @IInspectable - try think yourself. for access *lpNumberOfBytesRead* after *ReadFile* return - this pointer must be **saved** somewhere. this can be done only in kernel (inside *IRP*) - user mode nothing save. for save it in kernel - *lpNumberOfBytesRead* must be somehow passed to *ZwReadFile* (gate to the kernel and documented api). but *ZwReadFile* not have any parameters for *lpNumberOfBytesRead* - it not passed, not saved and can not be accessed after *ReadFile* return.

Comment: really *lpNumberOfBytesRead* only win32 layer trick. *ReadFile*, after *ZwReadFile* return ( 0 <= status && status != STATUS_PENDING ) simply do copy `*lpNumberOfBytesRead = IoStatusBlock->Information`. no sense at all do this on nt-layer. simply need look in *Information* member of `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`. but win32 layer unites *IOSB* with *ByteOffset* and *Event* to single parameter *OVERLAPPED* and by some reason try "hide" *IOSB* (rename it members to *Internal* and *InternalHigh*). anyway this trick ended after *ReadFile* return - *lpNumberOfBytesRead* not used anymore (because not saved )

Comment: @rbm The implementation is not the contract. I was asking about contractual guarantees.

Comment: @IInspectable - this is fundamental. and can not be another implementation.